# Two bag limit on Hand/Carry On Baggage at Heathrow?

Tags: transit, airport-security, hand-luggage, lhr

I heard that Heathrow Airport has a 2 bag limit when going through security.
How strictly do they enforce this?
If i have my carry-on and personal item and a plastic shopping bag/carrier bag is that an issue?
Is it any different going through connections?

Comment: [Apparently the two-bag limit exists](http://www.heathrow.com/departures/security-and-baggage), but I have seen plenty of people take more. As far as I can see, security isn't really interested in policing hand baggage sizes, although if you really took the mickey I suppose they might say something. A carrier bag with some shopping is not likely to be a problem. Connections security is pretty much the same as anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen security caring about the number of bags when your going through security. As a matter of fact, they probably not even aware whose bag is it, unless they see something suspicious in one, and they need to do a manual check in front of the owner.

On the other hand, can you put your shopping bag into your carry on?

However, it might be a problem at the gate, some airlines might be more strict than others with the number of hand baggage items.